# Can a LyX (RCS) "revert to repository version" be undone?

Tags: lyx

In LyX I accidentally clicked 'Version Control' -> 'Revert to Repository Version' as it's just below 'Check In changes' option.

This resulted in loss of all work since last check in, and using 'redo' is not possible. Is it possible to undo a revert like this?

Comment: It would very much depend on the version control system that LyX has been set up to work with, but unfortunately it's not likely that you can recover this work.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to restore your edits, hence the explicit warning by LyX:

[image]

As you have observed, LyX clears the undo/redo stack in such case. I was hoping that one of the backup files LyX generates may come as a rescue: Depending on the settings, LyX keeps for each file `doc.lyx` two backup files:

- `doc.lyx~` is copied from `doc.lyx` before a Save command, so that it always contains the previous generation and an accidental Save command can be undone.
- `#doc.lyx#` is generated by LyX's autosave feature, usually every five minutes.

However, when issuing a *Revert to Repository Version*, LyX unfortunately deletes `#doc.lyx#` and overwrites `doc.lyx~` as well with the repositry version.